# Group text - I can't reply all

Tags: sms

I have a group of ladies that are in the states (not sure if that makes a difference)
that have a group text going.
They see the group when they respond and they respond to the group

I see what the group sends out - but as individual messages and when I reply it only goes back to the person who sent the tect I replied to - not the group

anyone got any ideas?

Comment: iMessage group or MMS group?

Comment: What version of iOS are you using, and are they using iOS devices for the group chat? If so, are they using iMessage?

Answer (score 1):

If you send a group message on your iPhone, anyone else who uses iMessage will respond to the entire group, but that is not the case in your situation.

If one or more recipients is using standard SMS (on an Android, etc.), their response will be a standard SMS message back to you.

You can not prevent getting single messages as replies as long the group is not on same system.

In your case you can create a group in your contacts, then use it to reply to all (from the single message you got).

Here are [more details](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202724) from Apple how to.

> You can send a message to two or more people at a time using SMS, MMS,
>   and iMessage. You can send messages to multiple people with group
>   messaging and have any responses delivered to everyone in the group.